# Video not played in Flutter Android app but on iOS app

Tags: flutter

I have a screen that receives a video URL and should play it just after downloading the file.

I am using the video_player package.

This is the current screen code:

```
class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final videoUrl;

  VideoPlayerScreen({@required this.videoUrl});

  @override
  _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Create and store the VideoPlayerController. The VideoPlayerController
    // offers several different constructors to play videos from assets, files,
    // or the internet.
    print("VIDEO A REPRODUCIR ${widget.videoUrl}");

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.videoUrl)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _controller.value.isInitialized
            ? AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              )
            : Container(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _controller.value.isPlaying
                ? _controller.pause()
                : _controller.play();
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

EDITED:

Print output for the video URL:

```
https://appcapenergy.com/administrar/application/admin/tutoriales/TRgbwsproductionID_4114797.mp4
```

Error output for the Android App:

```
I/flutter ( 7815): VIDEO A REPRODUCIR https://appcapenergy.com/administrar/application/admin/tutoriales/TRgbwsproductionID_4114797.mp4

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 7815):       ... 11 more
E/flutter ( 7815): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640034, -1, null, [3840, 2160, 50.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=NO_EXCEEDS_CAPABILITIES, null, null)
E/flutter ( 7815):
```

Comment: are you using actual device? emulator is known to not render video on android sometimes.

Comment: @Rahul, I am using real device for android and iOS. The video is played on iOS but not on Android

Comment: I tried on my device. It is loading slowly. I would suggest move the file to some cdn service and see if there is any loading issue resolution on its own.

Comment: video was able to play on android device. it took almost 10 seconds to load.